# Wordpress Plugin Create Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Trying to create a pair of database tables within my table. Below is the code block that is being executed on the activation of my plugin. Wordpress reports that it's successful, however, when refreshing the database the employee table is not being created. The department table however is created successfully.

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );     

    // create the database table.        
    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "plugin_department";
    $table_name2 = $wpdb->prefix . "plugin_employee";

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
        name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY  KEY (id)
        ) $charset_collate;";

     $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE $table_name2 (
        id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,     
        first_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        last_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        department_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY  KEY (id),
        CONSTRAINT department_id
        FOREIGN KEY (id)
        REFERENCES plugin_department (id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
        ) $charset_collate;";                

    dbDelta($sql);        
    dbDelta($sql2);
```

Ideas on how to resolve would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the issue, using mysql workbench I had it generate the create table script for me, then was a simple copy and paste into the $sql2 variable. My assumption is that there must be a wonky character or a syntax error that is hard for my eyes to pick out.

```
     $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE $table_name2 (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `department_id` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      INDEX `wp_plugin_employee_department_idx` (`department_id` ASC),
      CONSTRAINT `wp_plugin_employee_department`
        FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`)
        REFERENCES `plugin_intranet`.`wp_plugin_department` (`id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)";
```

Comment: Sorry for the previous post. I am bit out of mind today but this link may help you http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table

Answer (score 0):

**Create Table**

```
global $wpdb;
if ($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '{$wpdb->prefix}tabloadi'") != $wpdb->prefix . 'tabloadi'){
   $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}tabloadi(
   id integer not null auto_increment,
   alan1 TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   alan2 TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   alan3 TINYTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   alan4tarih TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
   );");
}
```

**SELECT**

```
global $wpdb;
$tabloadi = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}tabloadi WHERE sart1=$deger1" );


foreach($tabloadi as $row)
{
echo $row->id;
echo $row->alan1;
echo $row->tarih;
}
```

**Delete**

```
global $wpdb;
$delete = $wpdb->delete($wpdb->prefix.'tabloadi',array('alan1'=>$alan1deger,'alan2'=>$alan2deger));
```